# How to insert data from metabox to custom table

Tags: php, metabox

I have created a custom table to save post data from custom meta box

And I have a problem in saving data from custom meta box to custom table

so this is my `function save_meeting_meta_box()`

```
function save_meeting_meta_box($post_id)
{
    if (!isset($_POST["meta-box-nonce"]) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST["meta-box-nonce"], basename(__FILE__)))
        return $post_id;
    if(!current_user_can("edit_post", $post_id))
        return $post_id;
    if(defined("DOING_AUTOSAVE") && DOING_AUTOSAVE)
        return $post_id;

    $slug = "post";
    if($slug != $post->post_type)
        return $post_id;

    $meta_box_text_value = "";
    $meta_box_dropdown_value = "";
    $meta_box_checkbox_value = "";
    $th_pax = "";
    $th_half = "";
    $th_full = "";
    $Theater = "Theater";
    $ClassRoom = "Class Room";
    $U_Shape = "U - Shape";
    $RoundTable = "Round Table";

    if(isset($_POST["th_pax"]) && isset($_POST["th_half"]) && isset($_POST["th_full"]) )
    {
        $th_pax = $_POST["th_pax"];
        $th_half = $_POST["th_half"];
        $th_full = $_POST["th_full"];
    }  
    insert($wpdb->prefix.'meeting_options', array(
                        'post_id' => $post_id, 
                        'post_setup' => $Theater,
                        'post_pax' => $th_pax, 
                        'full_price' => $th_full,
                        'half_price' => $th_half  
                    )); 
}

add_action("save_post", "save_meeting_meta_box", 10, 3);
```

So how can I insert data values of custom metaboxes into a database to specific table ?

I don't know if I should use `update_post_meta()` to insert data in custom table instead of `wp_postmeta`

Comment: You're going to have to use MySQL - Wordpress has a built-in database object to work with - [View Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try getting the values with the POST, then you can try this

```
$wpdb->update('meeting_options', array(fieldsGoHere);
```